# How to optimize Docker build for image with large web static content

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We need to generate a docker image which takes a very long time to build, maybe around 45 minutes to an hour. The build consists of first downloading many (100+) `.tgz` files from different npm locations, then decompress them to be served up by a web server (details will be omitted).

For simplicity, let's just assume there is exactly 100 modules, and that this app is just a combination of a bunch of different developer teams all delivering their web content to this one image. On-demand, any one of the 100 modules can get a new version with a new build, and that new build needs to regenerate a new image with 99 modules not changing, and only 1 module has now changed.

The build directory just before running the docker build command looks like this:

```
/build/libs/server.jar
/embeddedDir/
  module1-1.0.0/package/...
  module2-1.0.0/package/...
  module3-1.0.0/package/...
  module4-1.0.0/package/...
  // 100 modules in total
```

The `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM certifiedBaseImage:1.0.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY /embeddedDir/ ./embeddedDir/
COPY /build/libs/server.jar ./server.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["startmyserver"]
```

The first `COPY` layer takes so long to finish (45m-1hr). The "/embeddedDir" has maybe 2GB of just static content copied from various module packages from NPM. There are probably hundreds of thousands of small static files, css, images, etc.

It seems weird that 2GB of web content would take so long to copy into the docker image during the build. Especially if you consider that this build machine can download and decompress all this content in less than a minute, which is amazing speed.

So my optimization idea was to then just make an intermediate base image. So now I have 2 files like this:

`Dockerfile_base`

```
FROM certifiedBaseImage:1.0.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY /embeddedDir/ ./embeddedDir/
COPY /inventory.json ./inventory.json
```

The "inventory.json" is a list of all modules that are in the base image and their version.

`Dockerfile_new`

```
FROM intermediateBaseImage:1.0.0
COPY /embeddedDir/ ./embeddedDir/
COPY /build/libs/server.jar ./server.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["startmyserver"]
```

Before I build the `Dockerfile_new` I first pull the intermediateBaseImage, then copy the inventory.json from there, and make sure not to download any of the modules that are already there, so the embeddedDir only has files inside that are new in this build. It's OK to have older versions of a few modules in the final image, since the server only bothers to serve up the latest versions of each module anyway. I then have a separate build that generates the `Dockerfile_base` every week, and automatically updates the version on the `Dockerfile_new` to the updated base.

This SIGNIFICANTLY improved my build times by an order of magnitude. It went down from 45 minutes to build the docker image to 4 minutes.

But now my problem is that the security scans think my output image base is the intermediateBaseImage, and it complains that this image is not the "certified one". Of course my examples above aren't real base image names, just an example. But suffice to say the security scan doesn't trust the "intermediate one" that I generate once a week.

Here are my question:

Is there any strategy out there that can improve my build times but still have the final docker image be seen as having the certified base image (so the scans are satisfied?)

Answer (score -2):

[multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) are what you are looking for.

Comment: I did try this, by using a FROM <> as XX, then later copy files from XX to the final image, but the copy takes just as long and does not improve times.